# swift: Grand-Central-Dispatch but code is executed on mainthread?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch

Im importing data with an adressbookframework and storing the contacts within core data. The method is wrapped in GCD but the UI doesn't respond and all the code is executed on thread 1. What's wrong with my code?

```
func importContacts(){

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(Int(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND.value), 0)) {

            self.importContactsFromAdressbook() 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, you are using `dispatch_get_global_queue` and designating `QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND` as your operation queue. This will result in your block to be executed in the thread for the background tasks, which is not the main thread.

> The method is wrapped in GCD but the UI doesn't respond...

If I understand you correctly, you are attempting to update the UI in the block. This is not allowed. The Cocoa UI frameworks (including the UIKit and AppKit) are *not* thread-safe. Any update/interaction of UI elements must be done on the main thread.

So, if your `importContactsFromAdressbook` is concerning the UI, you should use `dispatch_get_main_queue` to send it to the main thread instead.

Might be useful: [Concurrency Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: found the mistake within the adressbook framework (wrapper): they called the mainthread again...  will delete my question